# Where to learn about writing test cases?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm a CS master student. Throughout my studies I coded many course projects in Java. Soon I will graduate. When I explore some github projects I often find people organize their projects as `/main` and `/test`. I have never organized it in such a way, i.e. I always have my source code files without any test directories. I think that folder often contains what I think is called 'test cases' or so.

Since I will find a job soon, then I would like to learn about production-quality code.

My questions:

- Why people often have that folder? What does it contain?
- Can you provide me with a link to a good tutorial about the practice of testing in java? i.e how to do it? In a nutshell I wanna understand the idea of that `/tests/` folder.

Comment: You want information about unit testing, not test cases.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/junit-tutorial-beginners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I often find people organize their projects as /main and /test

This is a matter of taste. Not 100% sure but at least [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) projects have such organization.

From [Maven: Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), this would be the project layout:

```
src
  main
    java <-- your Java source code
    resources
    filters
    config
    scripts
    webapp
  test
    java <-- your unit tests for Java
    resources
    filters
  it
  assembly
  site
```

> Why people often have that folder? What does it contain?

Usually, people write test cases to cover the code and check if the code works as expected. This is known as [Code Coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage). Code coverage also serves as regression tests in case somebody makes changes in the code for enhancements like code refactoring.

The test cases you will find them usually are for [Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). Depending on the type of the project, you could also find [Integration Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing).

There is also [Test Driven Development, or TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), which is a practice whose basis is writing the test cases before writing the real code.

> Can you provide me with a link to a good tutorial about the practice of testing in java?

This is off topic for the site. There are plenty tutorials on the net about this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a separate folder for mine but usually people keep their [Unit Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) in that folder. A unit test generally sets up "fake" data to test a given class so that a developer can easily debug any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason people provide a /test folder is to contain unit test for their project.

There are really many ways of testing Java but [JUnit](http://junit.org/) is a very commonly used method of testing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to write tests for your code. Begin with writing `Unit Tests`. I found [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/) very useful. Writing test ensures that your code behaves as expected , corner cases are tested and adding new code in the future does not break existing functionality.

There are also mocking frameworks like [`JMock`](http://jmock.org/jmock1-getting-started.html) and [`Mockito`](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) that make writing stubs and drivers for your methods easy.

What is even more interesting is people prefer writing tests before they write the actual implementation. This approach is called `Test Driven Development` or `Extreme Programming`. Writing tests first ensure one already has a prep code or pseudo code for the methods in mind.